# Python - Scanning photos on Google Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, scanning

I'm working on Kivy app which is trying to match someone face's photo with photos which are in my folder to check "is someone's photo in my folder previously?".

For example if I take my picture in real, and if I have my pre-taken photo on my folder, my app is matching these 2 pictures and says "they are same person". My code is working until now.

I'm trying to do this with online database with Google Firebase. I got a online folder which have many photos. I found a solution; download 1st picture on the database and try to match, download 2nd picture and try to match...

I think downloading photos everytime is not a good solution so is there any faster solution to scan photos on Google Firebase?

Comment: Could you include an [mcve]? It's not possible to answer without knowing what you've tried?

Comment: @ChrisLarson sharing even my code's little part is so unnecessary because my problem is so clear: "How can I scan the photos without downloading"